# Change DateTime to Midnight

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following `EffectiveDay` which I want to change datetime to the midnight.

```
public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
```

[image]

In the screenshot, it shows **02/28/2018 5:00:00 AM**.

I want to change it to **02/28/2018 12:00:00 AM (midnight)**

I tried the following approach, it did not work

```
ClassRoom.WorkOrders.Select(w => w.EffectiveDate).ToList().ForEach(s => s = s.Date);
```

I tried the following approach as well, it did not work.

```
ClassRoom.WorkOrders.Select(w => w.EffectiveDate).ToList().ForEach(s => s = GetDateZeroTime(s.Date));

public static DateTime GetDateZeroTime(DateTime date)
{
  return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: The screenshot shows `12:00:00 AM` which **is** midnight. Note that in .NET, a DateTime *always* has a Time component.

Comment: But if you check `TimeOfDay` shows 05:00:00 am

Comment: Why not just `.Select(w => w.EffectiveDate.Date)`? Or `.Select(w => GetDateZeroTime(w.EffectiveDate))`?

Comment: Note that the specific point in time is midnight UTC (note the Kind is Utc), and 5am in your timezone.

Comment: Where is the value for TimeOfDay being set?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Because OP is trying to set the time back into `w.EffectiveDate` by invoking `s = GetDateZeroTime...` inside `ForEach`.

Comment: Instead of your method, you can also use the .Date property of DateTime for the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `ForEach` with assignments after `ToList` are not going to help, because you are setting `s`, a parameter that is thrown away after each iteration.

Use a normal `foreach` loop to do the assignment:

```
foreach (var w in ClassRoom.WorkOrders) {
    w.EffectiveDate = w.EffectiveDate.Date;
    // w.EffectiveDate = GetDateZeroTime(w.EffectiveDate); would also work
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should effectively remove the time from all WorkOrders by assigning the `EffectiveDate` property of each one to a new `DateTime` object that has no knowledge of any kind of time:

```
foreach (var workOrder in ClassRoom.WorkOrders)
    workOrder.EffectiveDate = new DateTime(workOrder.EffectiveDate.Year, workOrder.EffectiveDate.Month, workOrder.EffectiveDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Setting `workOrder.EffectiveDate = workOrder.EffectiveDate.Date` in the loop should also work just fine.